# chat bubble showing overflow on long message in flutter

Tags: flutter

Here I am creating a basic chat app

and my chat bubble showing overflow error on long messages,, how to show whole message with multiline

and is there a way that I can whether get is it multiline message or single line, bcz I want to change design when it is multiline message , I mean to long message...

here is my code

```
class MessageCardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final MessageModel msgmodel;
  final bool sendbyme;

  const MessageCardWidget(
      {Key? key, required this.msgmodel, required this.sendbyme})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, left: 40),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment:
            sendbyme ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 255, 0.2),
                    offset: Offset(1, 1),
                    spreadRadius: 2,
                    blurRadius: 1)
              ],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              color: sendbyme ? Colors.green[100] : Colors.white,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment:
                  sendbyme ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  msgmodel.msg.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 2,
                ),
                Text(
                  DateFormat('hh-mm').format(msgmodel.createdon!).toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the `Text` widget with `Expanded`:

```
Expanded(
 child: Text(/*...*/),
)
```

Comment: its not working